# how to get csv files using wget

Tags: wget

I want to download some csv files from a webpage using wget. (This is the webpage http://sinca.mma.gob.cl/index.php/region/index/id/II). However using wget I only get some cgi-bin files and other format files which I suppose could build an csv file. Given that I have no knowledge at all on javascript or whatever is required to build the csv files, is there a way I could get those excel files using wget directly?

This is the log file after running wget 
--10:30:06--  http://sinca.mma.gob.cl/index.php/region/index/id/II
           => `sinca.mma.gob.cl/index.php/region/index/id/II'
Resolving sinca.mma.gob.cl... 190.215.49.125
Connecting to sinca.mma.gob.cl[190.215.49.125]:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]

```
0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........   28.17 KB/s
```

50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  226.24 KB/s
  100K .                                                         1.44 MB/s

Last-modified header missing -- time-stamps turned off.
10:30:09 (50.81 KB/s) - `sinca.mma.gob.cl/index.php/region/index/id/II.html' saved [103911]

Removing sinca.mma.gob.cl/index.php/region/index/id/II.html since it should be rejected.

FINISHED --10:30:09--
Downloaded: 103,911 bytes in 1 files
Converted 0 files in 0.00 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried to download just the excel files explicitly ? this may help figure out if the permissions are set up for sure.

Comment: Manually downloading the excel files can be done easily  without any permission and using wget I get no .csv file.

Comment: So is it a CSV file not an excel xls file ?

Comment: Yes right, it is csv file what you can download on that webpage.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide wget the full url that generates the file you want, for example:

```
wget -O test.csv "http://sinca.mma.gob.cl/cgi-bin/APUB-MMA/apub.tsindico2.cgi?outtype=xcl&macro=./RII/237/Cal/PM25//PM25.diario.diario.ic&from=13060100&to=15110323&path=/usr/airviro/data/CONAMA/&lang=esp&rsrc=&macropath="
```

I tested the above and I get the exact same csv file as I do when I click the link on the site. The link runs some javascript which generates the URL used above. To get that URL I clicked on the link, and then copied the address that appeared in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Wget dependant on the options will get all the files you specify, if you ask it to grab all the files that is exactly what it will do, unless the permissions do not allow those files to be downloaded, if you use

```
wget -r --no-parent http://www.example.com/folder/
```

That will pull all files, folders and subfolders of that directory unless you negate files of a particular type i.e:

To filter for specific file extensions:

```
wget -A pdf,jpg -m -p -E -k -K -np http://site/path/
```

Or, if you prefer long option names:

```
wget --accept pdf,jpg --mirror --progress --adjust-extension --convert-links --backup-converted --no-parent http://site/path/
```

This will mirror the site, but the files without jpg or pdf extension will be automatically removed.

So in answer to your question, yes you can just specify you want all excel files and nothing else.

If it still does not work your could try using the

```
-o wget.log
```

option to specify it to log to a file so you can see what's going on post up the log results and I will try to help you some more.

Comment: I tried using this command, however no csv file is found. Only empty folders are downloaded.

Comment: How long is your command running for ? Do you have enough disk space?

Comment: I just take a couple of seconds running but with no csv files found. I put the log in the question. Thank you very much.

Comment: right done a bit of research and from what I can gather there is a conflict with your .wgetrc file you need to hash out the --user-agent and try again

Comment: I included --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36" in the command and the log file remains exactly the same.

Comment: Try removing the --user-agent declaration all together and try specifying --max-redirect=2 or a higher number. You probably also want to specify --trust-server-names to allow wget to update the file name after redirection, otherwise the downloaded files will still be called download.

Comment: It seems my wget version does not allow --max-redirect (unrecognized option appears and in with the help that option is not on the list)

Comment: Is it possible to upgrade your wget version ? not that you should have to be it may be some dependency.

Comment: After looking apparently wget uses the robots.txt file which dictates how wget downloads the files, if the robot.txt is telling it to download just the html, try using the -e robots=off